# Get all siblings with sql inner join

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to get all the tasks by assignmentId, but I want it to also include any other assignments to the tasks. My current query looks like this

```
select * from task
inner join assignment
on assignment.taskId = task.taskId 
where assignmentId = 1
```

so that will return tasks 832 and 114, but 832 has 2 other assignments that will not be included in the dataset.

assignment table

```
assignmentId    taskId
---             ---
1               832
2               832
3               309
4               977
1               114
5               309
3               832
```

task table

```
taskId    body
---       ---
832       lorum
309       ipsum
977       numquam
114       whoops
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the tasks using a self-join:

```
select a.taskid
from assignment a join
     assignment a1
     on a.assignmentid = a1.assignmentid and
        a1.assignmentid = 1;
```

Then another join (or `in` or `exists`) brings in the additional task information.

Answer (score 0):

You want `exists` :

```
select a.*
from assignment a
where exists (select 1 
              from assignment a1 
              where a1.taskId = a.taskId and a1.assignmentid = 1
             );
```